# How to skip a column in array VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a source workbook and destination workbook and want to map all data from source wb to destination wb but the columns go in a specific order based on a mappings. Both source and destination header can be any length but the importance one will be the destination header because I don’t want to bring back all data just want data that i need based on mapping.

[image]

I got stuck on the loops where I need to offset the columns because when I am writing to the destination wb it will write column after column which is not what I intended. So if there is blank in the mapping then leaves that column as empty and move to next one and when writing this to the workbook the array should have same number of columns but the data in the right place. Any help will be greatly appreciated as I’ve tried various ways but always end up with wrong data or not working at all. The below works but when writing the data it dose without skipping whatever is not in the mapping so then I need to manually change the columns to fit the right data in the right column might as well do copy and paste but I thought array will be a lot faster at this task as the data is large in rows over 300k rows.

The picture is put together from different sheets and will not have the yellow row this is to make it clear what data belongs to what. The data mapping the first row will have the worksheet name where I will write the data.

```
Option Explicit
Sub DataTransformation()
    Dim wsDataMapping As Worksheet
    Dim targetWS As Worksheet
    Dim sourceWB As Workbook
    Dim targetWB As Workbook
    Dim destMapping As Range
    Dim destMappingCell As Range
    Dim srcData As Range
    Dim destData as Range
    Dim srcArr As Variant
    Dim destArr() As Variant
    Dim LCol As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim x As Long
    Dim sourceLRow As Long
    Dim targetLRow As Long
    Dim remainingFiles As String
    Dim time As Variant
   
    time = Now()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   
    Set targetWB = ActiveWorkbook
    With targetWB
        Set wsDataMapping = .Sheets("Data Mapping")
        Set targetWS = .Sheets(wsDataMapping.Range("A1").value)
    End With
   
    LCol = targetWS.Cells(16, targetWS.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
   
    Set destMapping = wsDataMapping.Range("A2:A" & wsDataMapping.Range("A" & wsDataMapping.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
   
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim fileName As Variant
    Dim allFiles As Collection
    Set allFiles = New Collection
    filePath = "C:\Users\" & Environ(“UserName”) & "\Desktop\Test M" & "\"
    'fileName = Dir(filePath & "*.*")
    Set allFiles = LoopThroughFiles(filePath, ".*")
   
For Each fileName In allFiles
 
    Set sourceWB = Workbooks.Open(filePath & fileName)
    Set srcData = sourceWB.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Set destData = targetWS.Range(targetWS.Cells(13, 3), targetWS.Cells(13, LCol))
   
    sourceLRow = sourceWB.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & sourceWB.Worksheets(1).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    targetLRow = FindLastRow(targetWS, 3, LCol)
   
    If (targetWS.Rows.Count - targetLRow) > sourceLRow Then
        srcArr = srcData.value
 
        ReDim Preserve destArr(1 To UBound(srcArr, 1), 1 To UBound(srcArr, 2))
 
        For Each destMappingCell In destMapping
            x = 0
            For i = LBound(srcArr, 2) To UBound(srcArr, 2)
             
                If destMappingCell.Offset(0, 1).value = srcArr(1, i) Then
                    x = x + 1
                    For j = LBound(srcArr, 1) To UBound(srcArr, 1)
                        'Debug.Print srcArr(j, i)
                        destArr(j, x) = srcArr(j, i)
                    Next j
                End If
            Next i
        Next destMappingCell
       
        sourceWB.Close False
        targetWS.Range("C" & targetLRow).Resize(UBound(destArr, 1), UBound(destArr, 2)).value = destArr
    Else
        sourceWB.Close False
        remainingFiles = remainingFiles & " " & fileName & vbNewLine
    End If
Next fileName
 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox time & " after run " & Now() & vbNewLine & "Files remaining to process are " & vbNewLine & remainingFiles
End Sub
Function LoopThroughFiles(inputDirectoryToScanForFile, filenameCriteria) As Collection
 
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim fileNames As Collection
 
    Set fileNames = New Collection
 
    strFile = Dir(inputDirectoryToScanForFile & "\*" & filenameCriteria)
    Do While Len(strFile) > 0
        'Debug.Print strFile
        fileNames.Add (strFile)
        strFile = Dir 'returns a new file
    Loop
    Set LoopThroughFiles = fileNames
End Function
Function FindLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal FromCol As Long = 0, Optional ByVal ToCol As Long = 0) As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
If FromCol = 0 Then FromCol = 3
If ToCol = 0 Then ToCol = 10
For i = FromCol To ToCol
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
    If FindLastRow < lastRow Then
        FindLastRow = lastRow
    End If
Next i
If FindLastRow < 17 Then FindLastRow = 17
End Function
```

Comment: It is essential to document your code as you write it.  If you need to amend this routine in six or twelve months, would you remember why you wrote it as you did?  If a colleague had to amend this routine, would they understand why you wrote it as you did?  If you needed to seek help on a technical forum, would a stranger understand why you wrote it as you did?  This is particularly important if your reasoning is not obvious.

Comment: Consider `Set targetWS = .Sheets(wsDataMapping.Range("A1").Value)` and `Set destMapping = wsDataMapping.Range("A2:A" & wsDataMapping.Range("A" & wsDataMapping.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)`.  In worksheet “Data Mapping”, rows 2 downwards define the mapping but row 1 defines the name of the destination worksheet.  I only know this because I have worked through your code line by line.  Why do you need to specify the destination worksheet in this way?  I would have used a constant.  Something like: `Const WshtNameDest As String = "Line"`.

Comment: Consider `Function FindLastRow`.  What is the significance of 3, 10 and 17?

Comment: You process the data mapping within the main loop.  Is this because the columns are in different positions within different source workbooks?

Comment: @TonyDallimore Sorry for the confusion everything in the picture is in their own worksheet without the yellow row that was just to make it a bit clear what is what. In the data mapping the first row will be the sheet name where I want to write the data.

Comment: @TonyDallimore FindLastRow is offset the column to 3 so column C because that is where the data starts same with 17 but that is for row and 10 its like a default value if column was not passed to the function.

Comment: @TonyDallimore In the mapping the first column will have the exact headers that I need in the destination and the order is the same from top to bottom, the second column in the mapping is the source and potentially will have more or less columns in different order than the first column so will not match at all that is way I only need specific data form the source. So my basis to have the `destArrr` be as big as the destination headers and get specific data from `srcArr` and is srcArr is less than destArr columns then just put blanks wherever necessary so that the columns align.

Comment: @TonyDallimore Do you have a good source where I can learn how to document the code? I just need to see a good example how is done so I can learn. Thanks for pointing out this things.

Comment: I will start constructing an answer this morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

The code below works against my test workbooks.  I believe I have handled your offsets correctly.  Lines starting '### require amendment for your system. I believe the remainder of the macros will work without change.  Copy this code to a new module, adjust as required and try it out. The comments within the code should explain everything.  If the comments are not adequate, ask questions and I will update the comments.

```
Option Explicit

  ' * I have a naming system for my constants and variables that I have used for years.
  '   Having a system means I can look at code I wrote years ago and recognise the
  '   constants and variables.  If you do not like my system, design your own but do
  '   code without a system if you wih to easily maintain old code.
  ' * Col, Inx, Row, Wsht and Wbk identify the name as relating to a column, index,
  '   row, worksheet or workbook.
  ' * Col, Row, Wsht and Wbk are followed by Xxx which is a code or abbreviation
  '   identifying the worksheet or workbook.
  ' * Values for Xxx in these macros are:
  '      Map  for the Data mapping table.
  '      Src  for a source workbook or worksheet
  '      Dest for the destination worksheet
  '      This for the workbook holding the macros and the destination worksheet.
  ' * Next, Crnt, Last destinguish different columns or rows if necessary.
  ' * InxX is an index for a 1D array or collection. Since the use is ArrayName(InxX),
  '   X is usually a single letter.
  ' * ColXxxDataFirst and RowXxxDataFirst define the first data column and row
  '   within worksheet Xxx.  This allows the number of header columns or rows to be
  '   changed with minimum effect on the code.
  ' * Fldr identifie a folder.  If the code accesses both Outlook and disc folders,
  '   the prefixes OutFldr and DscFldr are used instead.
  ' If the purpose of a variable does not fit within the above system, I use the
  ' name of the purpose for the variable.  For example DataMap.

  ' These constants identify which worksheet within this workbook holds the
  ' mapping table and its position within that worksheet.
  ' Cells(RowMapDataFirst, ColMapDataFirst) is the top left cell of the table
  ' excluding any column headings.
  ' Cells(RowMapDataFirst, ColMapDataFirst+1)
  ' ### Adjust as required.
  Const ColMapDataFirst As Long = 1
  Const RowMapDataFirst As Long = 2
  Const WshtDataName As String = "Data Mapping"

  ' Columns to the left of ColDestDataFirst and above RowDestDataFirst-1 are reserved.
  ' The data mapping table specifies the first destination column as 1. ColDestDataFirst
  ' specifies the true first destination column. When moving source columns to the
  ' destination worksheet, the destination column is adjusted for ColDestDataFirst.
  ' If at the start of this routine, the last row in the destination worksheet is less
  ' than RowDestDataFirst-1, the column headings will be written to RowDestDataFirst-1 and
  ' the first data will be written to RowDestDataFirst. If at the start of this routine,
  ' the last row in the destination worksheet is not less than RowDestDataFirst-1, the
  ' column headings will not be written to RowDestDataFirst-1 and the first data will be
  ' written to RowDestLast+1
  ' ### Adjust as required.
  Const ColDestDataFirst As Long = 3
  Const RowDestDataFirst As Long = 18
  Const WshtDestName As String = "Destination"

  ' First data row of a source worksheet.
  ' Note this code does not allow for source worksheets having different
  ' numbers of heding rows.
  Const RowSrcDataFirst As Long = 2

Sub CollectAndTransform()

  ' Collects data from all the source workbooks in the source folder and saves
  ' that data to the destination worksheet within this workbook.

  ' The Source folder is defined by FldrSrc.
  ' A source workbook is any workbook within FldrSrc that contains a worksheet which
  ' has all the required source columns.
  ' The data is saved by column with the new column sequence defined by the Data mapping
  ' table.
  ' The position of the Data mapping table is defined by ColDataDataFirst,
  ' RowDataDataFirst and WshtDataName.  See below where the data map is loaded to
  ' DataMap for more information. The format of the data map is defined at the top of
  ' sub DecodeMapping().

  ' 20Apr20  Coded.

  Dim ColDestCrnt As Long
  Dim ColDestLast As Long
  Dim ColsDestName() As String
  Dim ColSrcLast As Long
  Dim ColsSrcForDest() As Long
  Dim DataMap As Variant
  Dim Filename As String
  Dim FldrSrc As String
  Dim RngSrc As Range
  Dim RowDestLast As Long
  Dim RowMapLast As Long
  Dim RowSrcLast As Long
  Dim WbkSrc As Workbook
  Dim WbkThis As Workbook
  Dim WshtDest As Worksheet
  Dim WshtMap As Worksheet
  Dim WshtSrc As Worksheet

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Set WbkThis = ThisWorkbook

  ' ### Replace by FldrSrc = "C:\Users\" & Environ(“UserName”) & "\Desktop\Test M" & "\"
  FldrSrc = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"

  Set WshtMap = WbkThis.Worksheets("Data Mapping")
  Set WshtDest = WbkThis.Worksheets(WshtDestName)

  With WshtMap
    RowMapLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    DataMap = .Range(.Cells(RowMapDataFirst, 1), .Cells(RowMapLast, 2)).Value
    ' Note 1: the lower bounds of a variant loaded from a range are always one
    '         regardless of the location of the range within the worksheet.
    ' Note 2: I have loaded DataMap starting at row 2 because RowMapDataFirst
    '         equals 2.  If you want the table to start at a different row, just
    '         change the value of RowMapDataFirst.
  End With

  Filename = Dir$(FldrSrc & "*.xls*")
  Do While Filename <> "" And Filename <> ThisWorkbook.Name
    Set WbkSrc = Workbooks.Open(FldrSrc & Filename, , True)
    Set WshtSrc = FindSrcWsht(WbkSrc, DataMap)
    If WshtSrc Is Nothing Then
      Debug.Print WbkSrc.Name & " is is not a source workbook"
    Else
      ' This workkbook is a source workbook
      ' Call DecodeMapping here in case column sequence differs between workbooks.
      Call DecodeMapping(WshtSrc, DataMap, ColsDestName, ColsSrcForDest)
      If RowDestLast < RowDestDataFirst - 1 Then
        ' This is the first source workbook so the destination worksheet
        ' has not been checked
        Call FindLastRowCol(WshtDest, RowDestLast, ColDestLast)
        If RowDestLast < RowDestDataFirst - 1 Then
          ' No data has been written to the destination worksheet
          ' Output column headings
          With WshtDest
            .Range(.Cells(RowDestDataFirst - 1, ColDestDataFirst), _
                   .Cells(RowDestDataFirst - 1, ColDestDataFirst + _
                                                UBound(ColsDestName) - 1)).Value = ColsDestName
          End With
          RowDestLast = RowDestDataFirst - 1
        End If
      End If
      Call FindLastRowCol(WshtSrc, RowSrcLast, ColSrcLast)
      ' For each destination column which is not to be left empty,
      ' copy the appropriate source column to it.
      ' If ColDestCrnt(N) <> 0, source column ColDestCrnt(N) is to be copied
      ' to destination column N + ColDestDatFirst - 1
      ' A source column is from RowSrcDataFirst to RowSrcLast
      For ColDestCrnt = 1 To UBound(ColsSrcForDest)
        If ColsSrcForDest(ColDestCrnt) <> 0 Then
          With WshtSrc
            Set RngSrc = .Range(.Cells(RowSrcDataFirst, ColsSrcForDest(ColDestCrnt)), _
                                .Cells(RowSrcLast, ColsSrcForDest(ColDestCrnt)))
          End With
          Debug.Print WbkSrc.Name & "." & WshtSrc.Name & "Range("; RngSrc.Address & " ) -> " & _
                      WshtDest.Cells(RowDestLast + 1, ColDestCrnt + ColDestDataFirst - 1).Address
          RngSrc.Copy WshtDest.Cells(RowDestLast + 1, ColDestCrnt + ColDestDataFirst - 1)
        End If
      Next
      RowDestLast = RowDestLast + RngSrc.Rows.Count   ' Advance to bottom of data just copied
                                                      ' ready for next source workbook
    End If
    WbkSrc.Close
    Filename = Dir$
  Loop

  WshtDest.Columns.AutoFit

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
Sub DecodeMapping(ByRef WshtSrc As Worksheet, ByRef DataMap As Variant, _
                  ByRef ColsDestName() As String, ByRef ColsSrcForDest() As Long)

  ' Decodes a table mapping source column names to destination column names.

  ' Create an array of column headings for the destination worksheet.
  ' Locates the source column names within the source worksheet and creates an
  ' array mapping the source column numbers to the destination columns.

  ' WshtSrc        The source worksheet
  ' DataMap        A Variant holding a 2D table with 2 columns and 1 row per
  '                destination column.  Table column 1 contains the names of the
  '                destination columns in output sequence with table row N
  '                holding the name of destination column N.  Table column 2 of
  '                row N contains the name of the source column, if any, for the
  '                destination column whose name is in table column 1 or row N.
  ' ColsDestNames  On exit, the names of the destination columns in an array
  '                ready to be loaded to the header row of the destination
  '                worksheet.
  ' ColsSrcForDest On exit, ReDimmed to (1 To M) where M is the number of columns
  '                in the destination worksheet.  If ColsSrcForDest(P) = 0,
  '                destination column P is left blank.  If ColsSrcForDest(P) = Q,
  '                source column Q is to be copied to destination column P.

  ' 18Apr20  Coded.

  Dim ColSrcCrnt As Long
  Dim ColSrcLast As Long
  Dim Found As Boolean
  Dim RowMapCrnt As Long
  Dim RowSrcLast As Long

  ReDim ColsDestName(1 To UBound(DataMap, 1))

  ' Build array that can be used to create heading row for destination worksheet
  For RowMapCrnt = 1 To UBound(DataMap, 1)
    ColsDestName(RowMapCrnt) = DataMap(RowMapCrnt, 1)
  Next

  Call FindLastRowCol(WshtSrc, RowSrcLast, ColSrcLast)  ' Only need ColSrcLast

  ' Size ColsSrcForDest so there is one entry per destination column
  ' The entries are initialised to zeros.
  ReDim ColsSrcForDest(1 To UBound(DataMap))

  ' There are faster methods of achieving the source to destination mapping
  ' than these nested loops but the VBA is more complicated.  If there are
  ' so many source and destination columns that this is slow, I will recode.
  ' Match each value in column 2 of DataMap against a column heading in
  ' worksheet WshtSrc.  When a match is found, record the match in ColsSrcForDest.
  With WshtSrc
    For RowMapCrnt = 1 To UBound(DataMap)
      If DataMap(RowMapCrnt, 2) <> "" Then
        'Debug.Assert False
        Found = False
        For ColSrcCrnt = 1 To ColSrcLast
          If .Cells(1, ColSrcCrnt).Value = DataMap(RowMapCrnt, 2) Then
            ' Warning: this a case sensitive match
            'Debug.Assert False
            ColsSrcForDest(RowMapCrnt) = ColSrcCrnt
            Found = True
            Exit For
          End If
        Next
        If Not Found Then
          Debug.Assert False
          Call MsgBox("Source column name """ & DataMap(RowMapCrnt, 2) & _
                      """ appears in the DataMap but is not a column " & _
                      "heading in worksheet """ & WshtSrc.Name & """", vbOKOnly)
          End     ' Exit this macro and calling macro.
        End If
      End If
    Next
  End With

End Sub
Function FindSrcWsht(ByRef WbkSrc As Workbook, ByRef DataMap As Variant) As Worksheet

  ' Return a reference to the worksheet within WbkSrc that has all the columns
  ' required by DataMap for a source worksheet.  Return Nothing if no such
  ' worksheet found.

  ' WbkSrc         A workbook that might be a source workbook
  ' DataMap        A Variant holding a 2D table with 2 columns and 1 row per
  '                destination column.  Table column 1 contains the names of the
  '                destination columns in output sequence with table row N
  '                holding the name of destination column N.  Table column 2 of
  '                row N contains the name of the source column, if any, for the
  '                destination column whose name is in table column 1 or row N.

  ' Column 1 of DataMap is not used by this routine.
  ' Column 2 of DataMap contains column names that must exist within a source
  ' worksheet.
  ' Workbook WbkSrc can contain one or more worksheets. Match the column names
  ' within each worksheet against the column names in column 2 of DataMap until
  ' a worksheet is found with all required columns.  Retun a reference to that
  ' worksheet.  Return Nothing if no satisfactory worksheet is found.

  ' 19Apr20  Coded

  Dim ColSrcCrnt As Long
  Dim ColSrcLast As Long
  Dim InxNR As Long
  Dim InxWsht As Long
  Dim MatchAll As Boolean
  Dim MatchSingleFound As Boolean
  Dim NamesRequired As Collection
  Dim RowMapCrnt As Long
  Dim RowSrcLast As Long

  Set NamesRequired = New Collection

  ' Create collection of the column names required in a worksheet
  For RowMapCrnt = 1 To UBound(DataMap, 1)
    If DataMap(RowMapCrnt, 2) <> "" Then
      NamesRequired.Add DataMap(RowMapCrnt, 2)
    End If
  Next

  With WbkSrc
    'Debug.Print .Name             ' Name of workbook
    ' For each worksheet, attempt match on every required name
    For InxWsht = 1 To .Worksheets.Count
      With .Worksheets(InxWsht)
        'Debug.Print "  " & .Name    ' Name of worksheet
        Call FindLastRowCol(WbkSrc.Worksheets(InxWsht), RowSrcLast, ColSrcLast)
        MatchAll = True   ' Assume all names matched until name not found
        For InxNR = 1 To NamesRequired.Count
          MatchSingleFound = False    ' Have not yet matched NamesRequired(InxNR)
          For ColSrcCrnt = 1 To ColSrcLast
            If .Cells(1, ColSrcCrnt).Value = NamesRequired(InxNR) Then
              ' Have a case sensitive match between required name and column heading
              'Debug.Assert False
              MatchSingleFound = True
              Exit For
            End If
          Next
          If Not MatchSingleFound Then
            ' NamesRequired(InxNR) not matched against any column heading
            'Debug.Assert False
            'Debug.Print "    Required name """ & NamesRequired(InxNR) & """ not found"
            MatchAll = False
          End If
        Next
        If MatchAll Then
          ' Every required name matched against this worksheet
          Set FindSrcWsht = WbkSrc.Worksheets(InxWsht)
          Exit Function
        End If
      End With
    Next
  End With

  ' If get here, none of the worksheets contains every required name
  Set FindSrcWsht = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks this works like a charm. I did use Range.Value to copy things across but after testing with various data your approach with .copy I faster than Range.Value so I am going with your approach for the speed. It’s not major difference between the 2 but I imagine if the data is really big then you will see a significant performance between the 2. Thanks a lot for the detailed answer I learned a lot from you .

Comment: I am pleased that macro worked.  However, I am worried about your plan to use an add-in and having n workbooks.  It sounds as though you plan one macro workbook which become part of N destination workbooks and many more source workbooks.  It is unclear if the source and destination workbooks have different formats.  The current macro imports data into its own workbook using a mapping table that is also within its own workbook.  This would not be difficult to change but without a clearer understanding of your objective, I cannot advise you.

Comment: I have in the add in a macro that creates the necessary templates so the template were I need to import the data (destination) the headers will change and so will the headers from the source but I have another macro that creates the mapping so it will have the destination mapping and I will manually add the different sources as I don’t know before hand the source headers format. The way it is now I have tested it on different formats and tweak it were I needed it to work with this changes. Hope this was clear if not I’m happy to jump on a chat.

Comment: @QuickSilver  Sorry, I do not understand.  You could use the chat room attached to my first answer, but I imagine an email would be more convenient.  For me, an add-in is about distributing your code without letting your users see it.  Is that relevant to your need?  Even if an add-in is the best solution in the end, they are a pain in the neck during development.  Every time you make a change, you must re-install.

Answer (score 1):

**Designing and testing possible solution**

I would never try to design and code a routine like this in a single go.  I would divide it into steps; and I would code and test those steps separately if possible.  You have a block of code which does not work.  Was the error in step 1 or step 5?  I also look for opportunities to write my code as subroutines or functions that I can use again.

Consider `Function FindLastRow`.  You have coded this function in such a way that it is unique to this project.  Finding the last row and or column of a worksheet is a frequent requirement so creating a block of code you can use again and again would be useful.

You have used a technique for finding the last row of a column which is the probably the most reliable technique providing you know which column to test.  You have avoided the “which column?” problem by tested every column.  There are other techniques for finding the last row but none of the available techniques works in every situation.  My solution was to write a routine that used several techniques and picked the ‘best’ answer.  I do not worry which technique would be the best or fastest for today’s worksheet; I just use my standard routine.  A routine for today’s scenario might be faster but I have no time for programmers who spend minutes writing code that shaves milliseconds off a routine that is run once a day.

This is my routine for finding the last row and column of a worksheet:

```
Public Sub FindLastRowCol(ByRef Wsht As Worksheet, ByRef RowLast As Long, _
                          ByRef ColLast As Long)

  ' Sets RowLast and ColLast to the last row and column with a value
  ' in worksheet Wsht

  ' The motivation for coding this routine was the discovery that Find by
  ' previous row found a cell formatted as Merge and Center but Find by
  ' previous column did not.
  ' I had known the Find would miss merged cells but this was new to me.

  '   Dec16  Coded
  ' 31Dec16  Corrected handling of UserRange
  ' 15Feb17  SpecialCells was giving a higher row number than Find for
  '          no reason I could determine.  Added code to check for a
  '          value on rows and columns above those returned by Find
  ' 25Jun17  Found column with value about that found by Find

  Dim ColCrnt As Long
  Dim ColLastFind As Long
  Dim ColLastOther As Long
  Dim ColLastTemp As Long
  Dim ColLeft As Long
  Dim ColRight As Long
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim RowIncludesMerged As Boolean
  Dim RowBot As Long
  Dim RowCrnt As Long
  Dim RowLastFind As Long
  Dim RowLastOther As Long
  Dim RowLastTemp As Long
  Dim RowTop As Long

  With Wsht

    Set Rng = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
      RowLastFind = 0
      ColLastFind = 0
    Else
      RowLastFind = Rng.Row
      ColLastFind = Rng.Column
    End If

    Set Rng = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlValues, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
    Else
      If RowLastFind < Rng.Row Then
        RowLastFind = Rng.Row
      End If
      If ColLastFind < Rng.Column Then
        ColLastFind = Rng.Column
      End If
    End If

    Set Rng = .Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
      RowLastOther = 0
      ColLastOther = 0
    Else
      RowLastOther = Rng.Row
      ColLastOther = Rng.Column
    End If

    Set Rng = .UsedRange
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
    Else
      If RowLastOther < Rng.Row + Rng.Rows.Count - 1 Then
        RowLastOther = Rng.Row + Rng.Rows.Count - 1
      End If
      If ColLastOther < Rng.Column + Rng.Columns.Count - 1 Then
        ColLastOther = Rng.Column + Rng.Columns.Count - 1
      End If
    End If

    If RowLastFind < RowLastOther Then
      ' Higher row found by SpecialCells or UserRange
      Do While RowLastOther > RowLastFind
        ColLastTemp = .Cells(RowLastOther, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If ColLastTemp > 1 Or .Cells(RowLastOther, 1).Value <> "" Then
          Debug.Assert False
          ' Is this possible?
          ' Row after RowLastFind has value
          RowLastFind = RowLastOther
          Exit Do
        End If
        RowLastOther = RowLastOther - 1
      Loop
    ElseIf RowLastFind > RowLastOther Then
      Debug.Assert False
      ' Is this possible?
    End If
    RowLast = RowLastFind

    If ColLastFind < ColLastOther Then
      ' Higher column found by SpecialCells or UserRange
      Do While ColLastOther > ColLastFind
        RowLastTemp = .Cells(.Rows.Count, ColLastOther).End(xlUp).Row
        If RowLastTemp > 1 Or .Cells(1, ColLastOther).Value <> "" Then
          'Debug.Assert False
          ' Column after ColLastFind has value
          ' Possible causes:
          '   * Find does not recognise merged cells
          '   * Find does not examine hidden cells
          ColLastFind = ColLastOther
          Exit Do
        End If
        ColLastOther = ColLastOther - 1
      Loop
    ElseIf ColLastFind > ColLastOther Then
      Debug.Assert False
      ' Is this possible
    End If
    ColLast = ColLastFind

  End With

End Sub
```

This routine was written by me for me.  I am happy to share it, but it was not written to share.  The block of comments at the top are reasonably standard for my subroutines: what does it do, what are the parameters, why and history.  The structure will vary depending on the complexity of the routine and how long it took me to get it working correctly.  This routine has few comments within the body of the macro.  Consider the first block in which I use `Range.Find` to obtain the last row and column.  What comment would help understand this block?  If I had forgotten the syntax for `Range.Find`, a quick online search will reveal a page that explains it.  There are a few `Debug.Assert False`s left.  These are to catch situations I do not believe can occur but which I want to know about if they do.

I hold routines like this is PERSONAL.XLSB.  I have modules with names like LibExcel, LibOutlook and LibOffice which contain routines specific to Excel (such as this one) or Outlook or routines useful across several Office packages (such as reading and writing files).  Since they are in PERSONAL.XLSB, they are available to all my workbooks.  Search online for PERSONAL.XLSB if you want to know more.

I would divide your problem into three steps:

1. Locate each file in the target folder one by one.
2. Decode the column mapping table.
3. Apply the column mapping to the current file.

You might divide your problem up differently; it will depend on how comfortable you are with programming in VBA.  I have been using VBA for 18 years and I learnt my first programming language 55 years ago so I am comfortable although I have never thought of myself as a geek; for me, programming is just a means to an end.

I would not have thought of turning the Dir loop into a subroutine that returned a collection.  For me, using Dir to search down a single folder is so simple that I have never bothered to create a subroutine for it.  Searching subfolders makes the loop more complicated but, for me, not consistent enough to turn into a subroutine.  Decoding the column mapping table depends on how it is going to be used which means I must design step 3 first.

Copying an entire range to a Variant in one go is much, much faster than copying cell by cell.  However, copying from one array cell to another is not much faster than copying one worksheet cell to another.  I would use Range.Copy to copy an entire column for the source to the destination worksheet.  That is, I would copy source column 1 to destination column 2, 2 to 3, 6 to 6, 5 to 7, 4 to 8, 3 to 9 and 5 to 10.

To make the copying easy, I need that information in an array or perhaps a pair of arrays.  My choices are limited by the need to copy source column 5 to destination columns 7 and 10.  My best idea is:

```
Array Index       | 1| 2| 3| 4| 5| 6| 7| 8| 9|10|
SrcForDest        | 2| 3| 9| 8| 7| 6| 0| 0| 0| 5|
```

The array index identifies the destination column.  A value of 0 means that column has no source.  Any other value is the source column.  The loop becomes:

```
For Inx = 1 to 10
  If SrcForDest(Inx) <> 0 Then
    Construct source range
    Construct destination range
    Copy
  End If
Next
```

**Part 2**

I wanted to code and test the macro `DecodeMapping()`.  I created a macro-enabled workbook.  Within it, I created worksheets “Data Mapping”, “Source” and “Destination”.  I know “Source” and “Destination” are not the name you are using but currently this is just a testing workbook.

I entered your data mapping table into worksheet “Data Mapping”:

[image: Contents of worksheet "Data Mapping"]

If I have understood correctly, you have the name of your destination worksheet as cell A1 of this worksheet.  I think this is a bad idea.  My assumption is that you are trying to combine a lot of existing workbooks into one new workbook.  This will be a one-off conversion and you will never need to look at this macro again once the conversion is finished.  I do not like anything that is not obvious because I have seen it cause catastrophes when a new programmer did not appreciate why cell A1 had this strange value.  If you call the worksheet something like control data and clearly labelled the worksheet name and clearly label the mapping table then fine.  But naming a worksheet “Data Mapping” but having something else in cell A1 is bad practice.  I avoid bad practice even if it does not matter because it becomes a habit.  However, as I will explain latter, this does not matter.

I entered the column headings into worksheet “Source”:

[image: Headings for Worksheet "Source"]

There is no data because I do not need any data at this stage.

Worksheet “Destination” I left empty.

I created three modules which I named: “LibExcel”, “Mod Original” and “ModNew”.  I copied macro `FindLastRowCol` to module “LibExcel”.  I copied your code to “ModOriginal” so it was easy to reference.  I wrote macros `DecodeMapping` and `TestDecodeMapping` within “ModNew”.

This is a technique I use frequently.  To test `DecodeMapping` I create a test macro that simulates the eventual setting.  I do not have to worry about anything other than the needs of `DecodeMapping`.

The code within module “ModNew” is:

```
Option Explicit
Sub TestDecodeMapping()

  Const RowMapDataFirst As Long = 2

  Dim ColDestCrnt As Long
  Dim ColsDestName() As String
  Dim ColsSrcForDest() As Long
  Dim DataMap As Variant
  Dim RowMapLast As Long
  Dim WshtMap As Worksheet
  Dim WshtSrc As Worksheet

  Set WshtMap = Worksheets("Data Mapping")
  Set WshtSrc = Worksheets("Source")

  With WshtMap
    RowMapLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    DataMap = .Range(.Cells(RowMapDataFirst, 1), .Cells(RowMapLast, 2)).Value
    ' Note 1: the lower bounds of a variant loaded from a range are always one
    '         regardless of the location of the range within the worksheet.
    ' Note 2: I have loaded DataMap starting at row 2 because RowMapDataFirst
    '         equals 2.  If you want the table to start at a different row, just
    '         change the value of RowMapDataFirst.
  End With

  Call DecodeMapping(WshtSrc, DataMap, ColsDestName, ColsSrcForDest)

  ' Test ColsDestName by loading it to the top row of worksheet "Destination."
  With Worksheets("Destination")
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, UBound(ColsDestName))).Value = ColsDestName
  End With

  ' Test ColsSrcForDest by outoutting an anotated list of its contents.
  For ColDestCrnt = 1 To UBound(ColsSrcForDest)
    Debug.Print "Destination column " & ColDestCrnt & " (" & DataMap(ColDestCrnt, 1) & _
                ") ";
    If ColsSrcForDest(ColDestCrnt) = 0 Then
      Debug.Print "will be left empty"
    Else
      Debug.Print "will be loaded from source column " & ColsSrcForDest(ColDestCrnt) & _
                  " (" & DataMap(ColDestCrnt, 2) & ")"
    End If
  Next

End Sub
Sub DecodeMapping(ByRef WshtSrc As Worksheet, ByRef DataMap As Variant, _
                  ByRef ColsDestName() As String, ByRef ColsSrcForDest() As Long)

  ' Decodes a table mapping source column names to destination column names.

  ' Create an array of column headings for the destination worksheet.
  ' Locates the source column names within the source worksheet and creates an
  ' array mapping the source column numbers to the destination columns.

  ' WshtSrc        The source worksheet
  ' DataMap        A Variant holding a 2D table with 2 columns and 1 row per
  '                destination column.  Table column 1 contains the names of the
  '                destination columns in output sequence with table row N
  '                holding the name of destination column N.  Table column 2 of
  '                row N contains the name of the source column, if any, for the
  '                destination column whose name is in table column 1 or row N.
  ' ColsDestNames  On exit, the names of the destination columns in an array
  '                ready to be loaded to the header row of the destination
  '                worksheet.
  ' ColsSrcForDest On exit, ReDimmed to (1 To M) where M is the number of columns
  '                in the destination worksheet.  If ColsSrcForDest(P) = 0,
  '                destination column P is left blank.  If ColsSrcForDest(P) = Q,
  '                source column Q is to be copied to destination column P.

  ' 18Apr20  Coded.

  Dim ColSrcCrnt As Long
  Dim ColSrcLast As Long
  Dim Found As Boolean
  Dim RowDataCrnt As Long
  Dim RowSrcLast As Long

  ReDim ColsDestName(1 To UBound(DataMap, 1))

  ' Build array that can be used to create heading row for destination worksheet
  For RowDataCrnt = 1 To UBound(DataMap, 1)
    ColsDestName(RowDataCrnt) = DataMap(RowDataCrnt, 1)
  Next

  Call FindLastRowCol(WshtSrc, RowSrcLast, ColSrcLast)  ' Only need ColSrcLast

  ' Size ColsSrcForDest so there is one entry per destination column
  ' The entries are initialised to zeros.
  ReDim ColsSrcForDest(1 To UBound(DataMap))

  ' There are faster methods of achieving the source to destination mapping
  ' than these nested loops but the VBA is more complicated.  If there are
  ' so many source and destination columns that this is slow, I will recode.
  ' Match each value in column 2 of DataMap against a column heading in
  ' worksheet WshtSrc.  When a match is found, record the match in ColsSrcForDest.
  With WshtSrc
    For RowDataCrnt = 1 To UBound(DataMap)
      If DataMap(RowDataCrnt, 2) <> "" Then
        'Debug.Assert False
        Found = False
        For ColSrcCrnt = 1 To ColSrcLast
          If .Cells(1, ColSrcCrnt).Value = DataMap(RowDataCrnt, 2) Then
            ' Warning: this a case sensitive match
            'Debug.Assert False
            ColsSrcForDest(RowDataCrnt) = ColSrcCrnt
            Found = True
            Exit For
          End If
        Next
        If Not Found Then
          Debug.Assert False
          Call MsgBox("Source column name """ & DataMap(RowDataCrnt, 2) & _
                      """ appears in the DataMap but is not a column " & _
                      "heading in worksheet """ & WshtSrc.Name & """", vbOKOnly)
          End     ' Exit this macro and calling macro.
        End If
      End If
    Next
  End With

End Sub
```

Notes:

- Macro `TestDecodeMapping ()` does all the preparation.  It loads variant `DataMap` from the worksheet.  `DecodeMapping ()` does not know how `DataMap` was created.  If you want to load `DataMap` from lower down worksheet “Data Mapping”, no change will be required to `DecodeMapping ()`
- `DecodeMapping` does not do any offsetting.  The offsetting should be in the main routine, so it is obvious.  We were taught: no hidden side-effects.  If a new programmer takes over a program, everything should be obvious.  If a routine is named DoX then it should do X and nothing else.
- See how I test the output from `DecodeMapping ()`.  I want to be 100% confident that `DecodeMapping ()` works correctly before I use it in my main
  Routine.
- I believe I have included enough comments for you to understand my code but ask questions as necessary.

**Part 3**

The next issue is finding the source workbooks and validating the source worksheets.

You assume that every file within "C:\Users\" & Environ(“UserName”) & "\Desktop\Test M" is a source workbook.  Since you control the contents of this folder, this may be a reasonable assumption unless the workbook containing the macros and the destination worksheet is also within that folder.

You assume that the source worksheet is always Sheet(1) and that every worksheet contains every source column.  Again, these might be reasonable assumptions but your macro would fail if even one source workbook was not exactly as you assume.  I do not know how many of these source workbooks exist since your question implies there is only one.  It is function `LoopThroughFiles()` that indicates there are multiple source workbooks.  If you control these workbooks, you may know they are all the same.  But if someone else controls them, any assumption is dangerous.  It is easy to add another worksheet to a workbook by design or accident.

I have written Function `FindSrcWsht()`, which makes no assumptions, and I have written Sub `TestFindSrcWsht()` to test it and demonstrate how I would find and check these workbooks.

I created five workbooks that match my understanding of your source workbooks.  Some have extra columns, some have the columns in a different sequence and some have missing columns.  You do not need to create test workbooks since you have the real ones.

Near the beginning of `TestFindSrcWsht()` you will find `Path = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"`.  You need to replace this with `Path = "C:\Users\" & Environ(“UserName”) & "\Desktop\Test M" & "\"`.  Apart from that, I believe the macros will work without changes.  The output will be something like:

```
Test Data 1.xlsx
  Source
  This is a source workbook
Test Data 2.xlsx
  Sheet1
    Required name "Trans qty" not found
    Required name "Name" not found
    Required name "Color" not found
    Required name "Name" not found
  Source
  This is a source workbook
Test Data 3.xlsx
  Sheet1
    Required name "Style no" not found
    Required name "Item number" not found
    Required name "Trans qty" not found
    Required name "Name" not found
    Required name "Color" not found
    Required name "Size" not found
    Required name "Name" not found
  Sheet2
    Required name "Style no" not found
    Required name "Item number" not found
    Required name "Trans qty" not found
    Required name "Name" not found
    Required name "Color" not found
    Required name "Size" not found
    Required name "Name" not found
  Source
  This is a source workbook
Test Data 4.xlsx
  Source
    Required name "Name" not found
    Required name "Name" not found
  This is not a source workbook
Test Data 5.xlsx
  Source
    Required name "Style no" not found
  This is not a source workbook
```

The new code is:

```
Sub TestFindSrcWsht()

  Const RowMapDataFirst As Long = 2

  Dim DataMap As Variant
  Dim Filename As String
  Dim Path As String
  Dim RowMapLast As Long
  Dim WbkSrc As Workbook
  Dim WshtMap As Worksheet

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Set WshtMap = Worksheets("Data Mapping")

  With WshtMap
    RowMapLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    DataMap = .Range(.Cells(RowMapDataFirst, 1), .Cells(RowMapLast, 2)).Value
    ' Note 1: the lower bounds of a variant loaded from a range are always one
    '         regardless of the location of the range within the worksheet.
    ' Note 2: I have loaded DataMap starting at row 2 because RowMapDataFirst
    '         equals 2.  If you want the table to start at a different row, just
    '         change the value of RowMapDataFirst.
  End With

  Path = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"

  Filename = Dir$(Path & "*.xls*")
  Do While Filename <> "" And Filename <> ThisWorkbook.Name
    Set WbkSrc = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename, , True)
    If FindSrcWsht(WbkSrc, DataMap) Is Nothing Then
      Debug.Print "  This is not a source workbook"
    Else
      Debug.Print "  This is a source workbook"
    End If
    WbkSrc.Close
    Filename = Dir$
  Loop

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
Function FindSrcWsht(ByRef WbkSrc As Workbook, ByRef DataMap As Variant) As Worksheet

  ' Return a reference to the worksheet within WbkSrc that has all the columns
  ' required by DataMap for a source worksheet.  Return Nothing if no such
  ' worksheet found.

  ' WbkSrc         A workbook that might be a source workbook
  ' DataMap        A Variant holding a 2D table with 2 columns and 1 row per
  '                destination column.  Table column 1 contains the names of the
  '                destination columns in output sequence with table row N
  '                holding the name of destination column N.  Table column 2 of
  '                row N contains the name of the source column, if any, for the
  '                destination column whose name is in table column 1 or row N.

  ' Column 1 of DataMap is not used by this routine.
  ' Column 2 of DataMap contains column names that must exist within a source
  ' worksheet.
  ' Workbook WbkSrc can contain one or more worksheets. Match the column names
  ' within each worksheet against the column names in column 2 of DataMap until
  ' a worksheet is found with all required columns.  Retun a reference to that
  ' worksheet.  Return Nothing if no satisfactory worksheet is found.

  ' 19Apr20  Coded

  Dim ColSrcCrnt As Long
  Dim ColSrcLast As Long
  Dim InxNR As Long
  Dim InxWsht As Long
  Dim MatchAll As Boolean
  Dim MatchSingleFound As Boolean
  Dim NamesRequired As Collection
  Dim RowDataCrnt As Long
  Dim RowSrcLast As Long

  Set NamesRequired = New Collection

  ' Create collection of the column names required in a worksheet
  For RowDataCrnt = 1 To UBound(DataMap, 1)
    If DataMap(RowDataCrnt, 2) <> "" Then
      NamesRequired.Add DataMap(RowDataCrnt, 2)
    End If
  Next

  With WbkSrc
    Debug.Print .Name             ' Name of workbook
    ' For each worksheet, attempt match on every required name
    For InxWsht = 1 To .Worksheets.Count
      With .Worksheets(InxWsht)
        Debug.Print "  " & .Name    ' Name of worksheet
        Call FindLastRowCol(WbkSrc.Worksheets(InxWsht), RowSrcLast, ColSrcLast)
        MatchAll = True   ' Assume all names matched until name not found
        For InxNR = 1 To NamesRequired.Count
          MatchSingleFound = False    ' Have not yet matched NamesRequired(InxNR)
          For ColSrcCrnt = 1 To ColSrcLast
            If .Cells(1, ColSrcCrnt).Value = NamesRequired(InxNR) Then
              ' Have a case sensitive match between required name and column heading
              'Debug.Assert False
              MatchSingleFound = True
              Exit For
            End If
          Next
          If Not MatchSingleFound Then
            ' NamesRequired(InxNR) not matched against any column heading
            'Debug.Assert False
            Debug.Print "    Required name """ & NamesRequired(InxNR) & """ not found"
            MatchAll = False
          End If
        Next
        If MatchAll Then
          ' Every required name matched against this worksheet
          Set FindSrcWsht = WbkSrc.Worksheets(InxWsht)
          Exit Function
        End If
      End With
    Next
  End With

  ' If get here, none of the worksheets contains every required name
  Set FindSrcWsht = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the info much appreciated. To be honest I was thinking of using copy range but because I don’t know how large the data will be I ended up going for an array. Maybe I was wrong I thought will have a big impact in the process time. The other thing how will you set the numbers for the arrays because this will differ depending on the data so those numbers will not work all the time I assume you will have a loop that runs through the mapping and add the numbers based on that? I’ve never used assert I will need to research how that works. Do you have any good reading link?

Comment: Also in the array index when writing the data should we not add 2 to each number because the destination to write will be C17 onwards? Should we not account for that? Or will set the range to start from there therefore the count will be right? Nice  Find Last Row I never knew to account for all possible scenarios will be that long. Will have to go line by line and see exactly how it works. I guess experience is everything in the end I’m not even coming close to your experience years. Still much to learn I guess.

Comment: @QuickSilver  "Debug.Assert BooleanExpression" is the VBA version of a statement that exists in many languages.  If you search for "Assert Statement" you will find a number of pages describing them.  I use `Debug.Assert False` as an aid to testing.  I place `Debug.Assert False` at the top of every path through my code.  As I test my code and I reach those statements, I comment them out.  When I have finished testing, I look for any `Debug.Assert False`s that have not been commented out.  ...

Comment: If I find any, it means either my testing has not been complete or that path handles something that cannot happen.  The `Debug.Assert False`s left in `FindLastRowCol` identify conditions I cannot create but which I cannot convince myself are impossible.  If this code was for a client, I would output a load of diagnostic information to a text file and ask the client to email the file to me.  Since the routine was written for me, I am happy to risk reaching the `Debug.Assert False`.  ...

Comment: However, after three years of frequent use with many different worksheets, I should perhaps admit the condition tested for cannot occur.

Comment: Yes we will have to add offsets sometime but I am not sure where best to do that.  I generally get the basic code working and then decide where any non-standard code will be most obvious to a future maintenance programmer.

Comment: sorry if this might be a stupid question but debug.assert works on similar way as debug.print right so to the immediate window therefore will not stop the procedure right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211940/discussion-between-tony-dallimore-and-quicksilver).

Comment: Everything looks good and works as intended finds everything correctly. Now what remains is to do the copy and paste in a main module right?

Comment: I’ve done the copy paste in the TestDecodeMapping() and worked like a charm. I use .value to copy from one sheet to another. I try pasting the code here but it’s not letting me.

Comment: @QuickSilver  I have posted a new answer which I believe is a complete solution.

Comment: I am not sure what "I use .value to copy from one sheet to another" means.  Do you mean you copied Range.Value to a Variant.  If so, there is a better way.  See my new code.

Comment: what will be more convenient for you? I can do both but I think a chat room will be more interactive and get the q and a a lot quicker. What do you think?

Comment: I agree a chat room can be more interactive if we are both online at the same time.  The problem with chatrooms is limited size of text blocks and no formatting.  Try whichever you think is easier.

Comment: I have sent you an invite. Let me know if you haven’t received it.